# Google map V2 support devices

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using google map v2 api key. But it will support only higher versions of android devices only. It can not support in my android mobile of version 2.3.5. Is the V2 api only support for versions more than 3.0? If anybody knows please let me know.

xml file:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: shows us your xml and manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the V2 api only support for versions more than 3.0?

No, you can use `Google API V2` with Android API v8 and higher. You will need to use the `SupportMapFragment` instead of the `MapFragment` object. and to change you `Activity` to a `FragmentActivity` for backwards fragments compatibility. Of course you will need to add the android-support library to use this object.

You can take a look at this blog post I wrote with a full explanation on how to implement Google Maps API V2 for application that support android API V8 and up:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: Great @Arun, have a nice coding : )

Comment: How to add overlays in mapview. I cannot able to identify the mapfragment in my code.

Comment: when i am identifying the mapfragment i have to use fragment manager. But the fragment manager requires api level more than 11.

Comment: look forther in the comment of the blog, there is an explanation on how to get the instance of the map. There is no overlays in this version of Google Maps. use polylines and polygones to add lines and closed shapes to your map.

Comment: use supportFragmentManager like this: map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Answer (score 1):

You can use map V2 below API 10.Instead of using `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` use `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`and for the Activity useFragmentActivity.

Comment: If we using Fragment means that also need a version above 3.0?